# Google maps medir quilometragem entre dois pontos pelo horário

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps

Galera seguinte: tem como no google maps medir velocidade (quilometragem) entre dois pontos pelo horário de cada ponto exemplo:

- Ponto A (Lat e Long + hora tipo 10:00 hs)
- Ponto B (Lat e Long + hora tipo 11:00 hs)

Então a velocidade seria aproximadamente de 45 quilômetros por hora entre os 2 pontos exemplo !

vi nesse site abaixo isso preciso exatamente disso para um projeto alguém pode ajudar em algo ai ?

segue o link onde vi isso : https://www.sunearthtools.com/pt/tools/distance.php

Segue o código de como pego os dados ponto 1 e ponto 2 sendo que cada ponto tem a hora agora preciso saber a velocidade

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://api.findmespot.com/spot-main-web/consumer/rest-api/2.0/public/feed/0gUKvaesqck4s3oqr65sqUimR9gUjnSQd/message.xml');
$i = 0;
foreach($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message as $message) {
    $i++;
}?>

<?php $data_um = $xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[0]->dateTime; ?>
<?php $data_dois = $xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[1]->dateTime; ?>

Hora Ponto um:<?php echo  date('H:i:s', strtotime($data_um));?><br>
Lat Ponto um:<?php echo $latitude = $xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[0]->latitude;?><br>
long Ponto um:<?php echo $longitude = $xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[0]->longitude;?><br>


<hr> </hr>



Hora Ponto dois:<?php echo  date('H:i:s', strtotime($data_dois));?><br>
Lat Ponto dois:<?php echo $latitude = $xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[1]->latitude;?><br>
long Ponto dois:<?php echo $longitude = $xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[1]->longitude;?><br>
```

Comment: A velocidade em km/h será dada pela `distancia em km/horas`, sendo que a distancia no plano cartesiano é `sqrt((x2-x1)² + (y2-y1)²)`. Já tem o código que vai buscar os dois pontos ? Se sim coloque na pergunta.

Comment: Ola amigão poderia me colocar um exemplo ?

Comment: Já tem o código que vai buscar os dois pontos que está interessado assim como as horas ? Se sim pode colocar esse código na pergunta que eu responderei, caso contrário a questão torna-se demasiado ampla

Comment: Já amigão Isac tai o código de como pego os dados seria isso ?

Comment: De acordo com o link que você postou, a velocidade média é calculada de acordo com o tempo que o usuario indica que poderá utilizar para percorrer determinada distancia. Já no seu exemplo da a entender que você quer calcular a velocidade média usando a diferença de fuso horario entre os pontos A e B.